# Classify the singular points of $f(z)=\frac{\sin{z}}{e^{2z}−1}$. Evaluate $\int_Cf(z)dz$ s.t. $C$ denotes the positive sense of the circle $|z−i|= 3$.

Tags: complex-analysis

One easy singularity point is at $z=0$, but what's the best way to classify it? Also, I'm guessing there's more singular points in $f$. Also, what's the best approach to the integral? I'm pretty sure I'm to use the Residue theorem.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{2z}=1$ iff $z=n \pi i$ for some integer $n$. Since $f(z) \to \frac  1 2$ as $z \to 0$, the point $z=0$ is only a removable singularity.

The other points $z=in \pi$ where the denominator vanishes are poles of order $1$: $\lim_{z \to n\pi i} (z-n\pi i)f(z)=\sin (n\pi i)/2=i \sinh (n\pi)/2$. I will leave it to you to locate the poles inside your contour and apply Residue Theorem.